# Paypal payment process in Mobile App with Server and database

Tags: android, sql-server, paypal, azure-mobile-services, payment-processing

I am working on an Android App with Paypal Payment functionality. I have a question regarding the payment process.

Consider following two examples:

1. Client clicks order button in Android App. App connects to Azure App Service and sends some order information to it. The App service
   is processing that information and writes information to a MS SQL database table and sends it back to the App.
   After that the App has an order id, price and some other values and starts the Paypal process. After payment is done
   successfully,  Paypal sends a "PaymentConfirmation info" message to the App. The App connects to my App Service in order
   to write payment_status = "true". Now I can extract all orders from database with a Windows application(written by me) for further processing. For that I search all orders with
   payment_status = "true". After that I mark them with "order_finished" = "true" so next time I extract orders from database I only get new orders with payment_status = "true" and order_finished = "false".
2. Exactly like above, but now after Paypal sends a "PaymentConfirmation info" message to App, the internet connection gets
   interrupted(which is possible while driving car or in train) and so the App is not able to connect to my Azure App Service and so to the database to write the payment_status = "true".
   That means that my clients paid for their order, but I will never be able to process their order...big problem.

Question: What´s the best way to get a payment confirmation into my database for a specific order(according to order id)? What are other ways to get the paypal confirmation into the database?
How other Paypal payment processes work, or how do you achieve successful Paypal payment process?

Regards,

Adam

**Edited:(Answer to Adrian Hall)**

Consider my second example where the internet connection is lost,!after! the user paid for his order.
Saving some information to a offline table would no solve my problem 100%. Once the connection is lost and
the user(customer) is forced by me to establish a internet connection, so that my android app is able to set the payment_status = "true" (with help of the offline table) into my SQL Server in the Azure Cloud (with help of my App(Mobile) Service),
the customer could just interrupt the process. Otherwise it could be possible that he is just not able to get a internet connection back in a given amount of time so he is forced to close the App and maybe never starts my App again and so I would never get the payment_status ="true".
That would lead to the situation, that he paid for his order and never get´s his goods from me.

Isn't there any chance to connect the "order id" with the Paypal payment? I could then just extend my Windows Application and ask Paypal servers for that "order id" and if it is paid or not and then process that paid orders further.

**Edited:**

There is something called Paypal IPN. IPN contacts a given URL on your Server and sends some information to verify the payment. Maybe I should implement a IPN Lister on my Server...but how should I tell Paypal to send my generated "order id" together with the IPN request to my server so I can identify a specific order. I could then set the payment_status = "true" with help of the "order id".

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

With Azure Mobile Apps, you can make the database table "offline".  In this case, you write to a local SQLite database, then push the changes to the remote database whenever you want.  Most times, you would write to the SQLite database and then immediately sync.  If that fails, you can either retry on a timer, wait for [an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895720/android-wait-for-network-available) or for the user to push a button.  At that point, the changes would be synced.

Since you always have a copy of the data on the users device, you can always query the state from the phone, even when disconnected.  However, the remote database won't reflect the changes until the device connects again.

More information available at the Azure docs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data/

Comment: Hello Adrian! Please see my edited question. There is not enough space here to answer ;)

Comment: Looks like the IPN is a fairly straight forward protocol.  Assuming you have the transaction ID, you can update the payment status.  You would set up a standard ASP.NET Controller for the IPN then register that with PayPal.  Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ and a few examples, plus a whole getting started guide.  They also have a sandbox.  What is the problem?

Comment: I think the transaction ID is sent in the Paypal payment response object to my android client....but here again is the problem.--> Payment is done sucessful and response with transaction ID is send back to my Android client...I could use that now for my payment status....but what if the internet connection gets interrupted directly after I get the response? I need a way to pass my "order_id" into the payment and get it back in the IPN response, which is then send to my server to mark payment_status...how could I achive that?! Maybe I have made a mistake with my thinking?! I just do not now!?